# Can you run a login shell in Xterm?

Tags: command-line, bash, 20.04, login

I'm trying to get a hold of all the interactive/non-interactive login/non-login shells types, and I have a little question to help me put this puzzle together:

I understand that when you e.g. login to a remote machine with SSH you get a login shell. If I:

```
~$ logout
```

I get disconnected.

But when I open up a terminal in my Desktop Environment, can I get a login shell?
Because if I then try to

```
~$ logout
bash: logout: not login shell: use 'exit'
```

So is there a way to connect to a login shell locally?

Comment: You could run an SSH server and do `ssh localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question as posted, yes you can run a login shell in xterm by passing the `-ls` option i.e.

```
xterm -ls
```

From `man xterm`:

> ```
>    -ls     This option indicates that the shell that is started in the
>            xterm window will be a login shell (i.e., the first character
>            of argv[0] will be a dash, indicating to the shell that it
>            should read the user's .login or .profile).
> ```

You can start bash as a login shell in an existing terminal by passing the `-l` or `--login` option

```
bash -l
```

This will start the login shell as a child of the current shell; if you want to *replace* the current interactive shell with a login shell, you can use `exec`:

```
exec bash -l
```

Alternatively, [as suggested by Jos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302073/can-you-run-a-login-shell-in-xterm#comment2213520_1302073) you can install an SSH server and then login locally exactly as you would remotely

```
ssh localhost
```